# notify_one not triggering condition_variable inside dynamic library

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable, stdthread

I have the following project structure: one singleton class (with one processing thread that is waiting in a condition_variable) that is exposed from a dll file and an executable that is referencing the singleton. Through RAII, I am expected that at the destruction of the singleton (and the destruction of the internal implementation) the condition_variable is notified (with a notify_one).
This doesn't happen and the behavior is strange: the condition variable is not triggered, but somehow the main thread is joined.

Files from DLL project:

**Foo.h:**

```
#pragma once
#ifdef FOODLL_EXPORTS
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#pragma comment(lib,"FooDll.lib")
#endif

#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Foo_Impl {
public:
Foo_Impl()
    :_done(false)
{
    _writeThread = std::thread(std::bind(&Foo_Impl::threadRun, this));
}

virtual ~Foo_Impl() {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        _done = true;
    }
    _cv.notify_one();

    if (_writeThread.joinable()) {
        _writeThread.join();
    }
    std::cout << "Joined";
}

void threadRun() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    std::cout << "Prepare wait" << std::endl;
    _cv.wait(lock, [&] 
        {
            return _done.load();
        });

    std::cout << "Done thread" << std::endl;
}

std::atomic<bool> _done;
std::thread _writeThread;
std::mutex _mutex;
std::condition_variable _cv;
};


class DLL_API Foo {
private:
Foo_Impl* mp_impl;

public:

static Foo& getInstance() {
    static Foo instance;
    return instance;
}

private:
Foo()
    :mp_impl(new Foo_Impl())
{
}
~Foo()
{
    delete mp_impl;
}
Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
};
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Foo.h"
```

Files from executable:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "../FooDll/Foo.h"

int main()
{
    Foo& foo = Foo::getInstance();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); //allow some time so threadRun is running and waiting
    return 0;
}
```

I am building on **VS2019**.
The output that I am receiving is:

```
Prepare wait
Joined
```

If I am not using the Foo class through the Dll, and instead link it with the executable (class <strike>DLL_API</strike>  Foo) the output received is:

```
Prepare wait
Done thread
Joined
```

On **VS2013** for DLL version I'm getting same output:

```
Prepare wait
Joined
```

but for non Dll the thread is never joined:

```
Prepare wait
Done thread
```

**EDITS** : **Added predicate to condition_variable and locking the bool guard when it's flagged.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using condition variables incorrectly.

`_cv.wait(lock)` may wake up at any time with or without a notify. You need to associate a predicate with the condition variable, and either manually wrap it in a loop, or use the predicate overload of `wait`:

`_cv.wait(lock,[&]{return flag;});`, where `flag` is a `bool` set by the shutdown code while holding the lock, before notifying:

```
~Foo_Impl() {
    {
        std::lock_guard guard(_mutex);
        flag=true;
    }
    _cv.notify_one();

    if (_writeThread.joinable()) {
        _writeThread.join();
    }
    std::cout << "Joined";
}
```

Without doing this, then not only might the `wait` not wait, but the `notify_one` call might do nothing at all, so the `wait` might never wake.

Comment: I was not consciously aware of this. However, before posting I had this `Foo_Impl()
:_done(false)
{
 _writeThread = std::thread(std::bind(&Foo_Impl::threadRun, this));
}

virtual ~Foo_Impl() {
 _done = true;
 _cv.notify_one();

 if (_writeThread.joinable()) {
  _writeThread.join();
 }
 std::cout << "J";
}

void threadRun() {
 std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
 std::cout << "Prepare wait" << std::endl;
 _cv.wait(lock, [&] 
  {
   return _done.load();
  });

 std::cout << "D" << std::endl;
}

std::atomic<bool> _done;`
Same different result for Dll and non Dll

Comment: You still need to mutex lock even with atomic `_done`, in order to ensure the notify is correctly matched to the wait.

Comment: Added the atomic _done in lock. I'm still getting different behavior when the code is in dll (no wake) versus when it's not (wake and join ok). The only change I'm doing is removing DLL_API from the Foo class declaration. Also, on vs2013 the thread is still not joining on non dll version, even if the condition variable is waken.

Comment: I don't have VS to hand, but it might be due to DLLs not behaving well with respect to threads at shutdown. Can you try creating and destroying your `Foo` instance within `main` rather than as a global/static?

Comment: Yes, it works with Foo on the stack and not global. Thank you, sir! Now the question is if there is anything else to make a notification at program termination with static instance in a dll as I'm forced to use this approach in my project.

Comment: As a temporary solution I will add a cleanup method that will do the work of the destructor and will be called in DLLMain at DLL_THREAD_DETACH.